# Display div element onclick of the selected button over table data on a JSON array objects after it's rendered in React JS

Tags: reactjs, json, html-table, onclick, this

I have a JSON object like this:

```
import React, {useState}from 'react'

export const SitePrefData1 = [
{"groupid":"SFRA Unified Feature Cartridge","description":"Enables the In Store Pickup Plugin","preferenceid":"sfraEnableOverlayInStorePickup"},
{"groupid":"Agrex","description":"Enable Tls Perks JP","preferenceid":"tlsjpEnable"},
{"groupid":"AmazonPay_v2","description":"sample description1","preferenceid":"amzPayEnabled"},
{"groupid":"ApplePayConfigs","description":"sample description2","preferenceid":"isApplePayEnabledOnPDP"},
];
```

I wanted the description value displayed onclick of a button based on the index (like 0,1,2) passed, But it displays all the button description values irrespective of any index passed. For eg. if I click the first 'Description' button I expect only it displays 'Enables the In Store Pickup Plugin' but instead it displays all description values

I use axios and return response in JSON object and store it in array like this:

```
SiteFunctionality.js

const getSitePFunctionality1 =  () => {
        console.log("Site Pref length"+SitePrefData1.length);
       
            var jsondata = JSON.stringify(SitePrefData1);

            axios.get('http://localhost:3001/sitefunctionality1?sitedata=' + jsondata +
             '&site=' + selectedBrand+'&site_id=' + selectedSite).then(response => {
             setSitePreference(response.data)
            })
    }
```

While rendering data I have a button on individual table data using div element like this. I iterate over json map to display the saved response like this:

server.js

```
app.get('/sitefunctionality1', (req,res) => {

    var sitedata = req.query.sitedata;
    var site = req.query.site;
    var siteid  = req.query.site_id;
    var apiCalls = [];
    var eachresult={
        site_values : []
    }
    
    const sitejsonresult = JSON.parse(sitedata);

    for(var i=0; i<sitejsonresult.length; i++ ){
        
         apiCalls.push(getSitePreference(sitejsonresult[i].groupid,sitejsonresult[i].preferenceid,site));  
    }
   
    
    Promise.all(apiCalls).then(response => {
       
        for(var j = 0; j< response.length ; j++){
            
            var eachRes = JSON.parse(response[j]);
            
            if(eachRes.site_values){
                var keys = Object.keys(eachRes.site_values);
                for(var i = 0; i< keys.length; i++){
                    if(siteid===keys[i]){
                    
                    eachresult.site_values.push({
                        groupId : sitejsonresult[j].groupid,
                        description:sitejsonresult[j].description,
                        preferenceId : eachRes.id,
                        id : keys[i],
                        value : eachRes.site_values[keys[i]]
                    })
                } 
            }// end of for keys
        }// end of if
            
        }// end of outer far response
        res.json(eachresult);
    })
```

I am using a function getDescription which passes current key value to pass the current index value so that it display the json object value of the particular passed in index value.

```
 const getDescription = (inputkey,rownum)=> {

        console.log("input key ....  "+inputkey);
        console.log("rownum ....  "+rownum);
        //for (var i=0; i<SitePrefData1.length; i++){
        SitePrefData1.map((data,key)=>{
            console.log("groupid ....  "+data.groupid);
           // console.log("groupid ....  "+SitePrefData1[i].groupid);
            console.log("key ....  "+key);
          
                if(data.groupid===inputkey && key===rownum){

                    console.log("success loop ....  ");
                    setIsShown(true);
                    setDesc(data.description); 
                } 
            })    
         }
        }

` return(
        <>
            <button className='search-button' onClick={() => { getSitePFunctionality1();}} >S</button>
            
            {
            <table className='table-sitecontent'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style={style1}>Use Case</th>
                                <th style={style3}>Flag Status</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            
                        {
                sitePreference.site_values && sitePreference.site_values.length > 0 ?
                
                <>
                    <div className='site-preference__items'>
                        
                    {
                        sitePreference.site_values.map((item,index) => {
                            //for (var i=0; i<sitePreference.site_values.length; i++){
                            
                            return <div className='site-preference__item' key={'SitePreference' + index}>
                                 <tr >
                            <td style={style1}>{item.groupId}
                            <div>
                            <button ref={descButtonRef} onClick={() => {getDescription(item.groupId,index);}}  class="button-description">
                                 Description
                            </button>
                                {
                                (<div id={item.groupId}>
                                     {desc} 
                                     </div>)
                                }
                            </div>
                             </td>
                            
                            <td style={style3}>{getFlagStatus(item.value.toString())}</td>
                            </tr>
                        
                            </div>
                        })
                    }
                    </div>
                </>
                : 
                <div className='no-data'>
                </div> 
            }
                        
                        </tbody>
            </table>  
            }
                 
        </>
    )
```

But I am seeing that it displays description for all of the button description instead of the selected button or the index which am passing.

How do I pass the current selected button and display only that particular button description and hide rest other button descriptions:

[onclick result of the first button Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCPO9.png)